# JDO - How do I define a package in a declareParameters call?

Tags: java, package, jdo

I'm attempting to do a JDO query with a filter based on one of my own classes:

```
Query q = pm.newQuery(Child.class);
q.setFilter("parent = parentParam");
q.declareParameters("Parent parentParam");
List<Child> childList = (List<Child>) q.execute(someParent);
```

However, I keep getting the following error:

```
Class Parent for query has not been resolved. Check the query and any imports/aliases specification
```

Based on the information I got from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16494495/1191087), I need to define the `Parent` class package in the declareParameters call. How would this be done? Thank you much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some additional research and some trial and error, I figured it out:

```
q.declareParameters("com.mypackage.Parent parentParam");
```

Comment: or set the "imports" to the query